# Opening High Sierra system log files (tracev3)

Tags: macos, logging, macos-high-sierra

**How do I view High Sierra system log files?** Specifically I want to do so from recovery, or remotely.

In recovery, `log collect`  gives:

> “log: failed to collect LiveData: No such file or directory (2)”

`log show` doesn't seem work according to its documentation even on a normally booted up system e.g.

`log show --file Persist/00000000000000eb.tracev3` gives:

> log: Could not open tracev3 log file: The specified URL did not refer to a valid log archive

Even though the documentation states:

> --file file      Display events stored in the given .tracev3 file. In order to be decoded, the file must be contained within a valid .logarchive bundle, or part of the system logs directory.

which would seem to imply that .tracev3 should not need to be in a log archive, if they’re in the system log directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of recovery, first starting the `logd` daemon allows you to `collect` logs, which is a start e.g.

```
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.logd.plist
log collect --last 3h
```

I'm still unclear how one would do this remotely i.e. I still can't work out how to read an arbitrary tracev3 in the system directory with `log`.